# share subset of files under git with another repo, maintaining commits

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repo used to track changes in a set of small scripts (all functionally independent).

I also am part of a lab GitHub repo used to collect useful scripts written by various people in our group.

I want to push changes made to my scripts to the shared repo, but I don't want to have them be exclusively tracked under that repo, nor do I want modifications made there to overwrite my master copies.

The approach I've taken is to run a command to copy the scripts into the shared repo every time I change something, but this means I have to make a separate commit in that repo, too. Every time I Google this I end up at an answer mentioning `submodules`, but I feel like that's overengineered for what I want to do.

Is there any way to integrate commits from my primary repo into the secondary repo for only these files?

Comment: Did you end up with a solution? I have a similar problem, my approach will be to just write something to manage all of this called gitshards.py. It will keep track of where the last pull of a file came from (like the repo, the branch, and the commit hash). I can then pull changes from the main repos as `gitshards collect <filename>" or `gitshards collect --hash <remote commit hash> <filename>` and merge my changes as `gitshards patch --branch <remote branch> <filename>`.

Comment: @SimonStreicher I haven't been able to come up with anything better than what it looks like you've managed (and mine is much less sophisticated). This just really isn't a typical use-case for Git itself (afaik), so some amount of external scripting is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you'll run into is the phrase "commits...for only those files".  The complete content tree is an integral part of a git commit.  For example, if you use `git filter-branch` with the `subdirectory-filter`, it appears to modify every commit to remap a specific directory as the worktree root; but it doesn't *really* do that because it can't.  What it does is create *new* commits, with a history parallel to the old commits, with the modified work tree directory structure.

If you can structure the shared repository so that each contributor's scripts get their own directory, then submodules would indeed be an option.  I understand you feel it's over-engineered, but that's based on your thinking that moving "part of a commit" is an easy idea, which is leading you to underestimate how much complexity you should encounter.

Otherwise, I think finding a way to automate the copy-based approach is the best you'll get.

Comment: I didn't intend to cast aspersions with the phrase "over-engineered", I was just wondering whether there might be something much easier that I was overlooking. I recognize it's a bit of an esoteric case.